# Is this a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\{(x,y,z)|2x+9y=0, 8x-5z=0\}$$

I solved these as simultaneous equations giving me
the equation $36y + 5z = 0$ or $y=-\frac{5}{36}z$, which I can write as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{5}{36}z \\
z \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 0.$$

Substituting $0$ for $z$ satisfies this equation.
And it is closed multiplication and addition so this the original set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is that method correct or am I completely off with this?

Comment: You forgot to write $x$ in terms of $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you solve $y = -\frac{5}{36}z$, you should substitute into the first equation to find a relationship with $x$:

$$\begin{align*}
 2x + 9\left(-\frac{5}{36}z\right) &= 0 \\
 2x - \frac{5}{4}z &= 0 \\
 x &= \frac{5}{8}z
\end{align*}$$

This implies all vectors in the set can be written in the form:
$$ \left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c} \frac{5}{8}z \\ -\frac{5}{36}z \\ z \\ \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} \frac{5}{8} \\ -\frac{5}{36} \\ 1 \\ \end{array}\right]z$$

And this implies the set is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since it can be written as the *span* of some number of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

There are other ways to analyze the set, but hopefully this method is closest to what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=\{(x,y,z)|2x+9y=0, 8x-5z=0\}$. To check that $V$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we need to check $3$ things:

- $0=(0,0,0)\in V$,
- If $v\in V$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda\cdot v \in V$, and
- If $v,w\in V$, then $v+w\in V$.

Let's show that these three conditions are satisfied:

- $0=(0,0,0)\in V$: Indeed $2\cdot 0 +9\cdot 0 = 0$ and $8\cdot 0 - 5\cdot 0 =0$, so $(0,0,0)\in V$.
- If $v\in V$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\lambda\cdot v \in V$: suppose $v=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $v\in V$. Then, $2x_0+9y_0=0$ and $8x_0-5z_0=0$. Thus,
  $$2(\lambda x_0)+9(\lambda y_0) = \lambda (2x_0+9y_0)=\lambda(0)=0$$
  and
  $$8(\lambda x_0)-5(\lambda z_0)= \lambda(8x_0-5z_0)=\lambda (0)=0.$$
  Hence, $\lambda v = (\lambda x_0, \lambda y_0, \lambda z_0) \in V$ as well.
- If $v,w\in V$, then $v+w\in V$: let $v=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $w=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, and suppose $v,w\in V$. Then, $2x_0+9y_0=0$ and $8x_0-5z_0=0$, and $2x_1+9y_1=0$ and $8x_1-5z_1=0$. Hence:
  $$2(x_0+x_1)+9(y_0+y_1)= (2x_0+9y_0)+(2x_1+9y_1)=0+0=0$$ and 
  $$8(x_0+y_0)-5(z_0+z_1)=(8x_0-5z_0)+(8x_1-5z_1)=0+0=0.$$
  Hence $v+w\in V$ as well.

All three conditions are verified and therefore $V$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.